# Python - port pkl model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle

I've got a .pkl file containing a fitted GB Regressor model. This model was made under a python 2.7 environment, with sklearn 0.16.1.
Is there any way to import it in Python 3.5?

I've imported it into a 2.7 env, and I've managed to discover the parameters used to tune the model. But with this all I've got is an "empty", non-fitted 3.5 model.

Comment: The only thing which might work is installing the exactly same version of sklearn (in your python3 env) and load the pkl file. Maybe future versions might work too, depending on the changes to these algorithms used. This will need trial and error. But i would assume, that a negative case will throw some bad exception instead of beeing silent.

Comment: Try using sklearn's native joblib library, it should be a bit more robust to cross-version transfers, but as mentioned above, it depends on some other factors http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html#persistence-example

Comment: you should make sure you are using the same pickle protocol, if you used `2` (the `HIGHEST_PROTOCOL`) or `0` (i.e. the default) in 2.7, then you should also use the same version (`2` or `0`) in 3.5, not `4` (the `HIGHEST_PROTOCOL`) or `3` (the default).  If you `load` at the same protocol, you have a good chance of the pickle loading.  It might not, due to other language changes (e.g. a module name has changed), but it could work.

Comment: @Mike McKerns Wow... is the used protocol really not saved as metadata in the pickled file? I use pickle-wrappers most of the time (in numpy, sklearn) but this is very surprising.

Comment: @sascha: it's not. However, you can tell what protocol is used very easily by the first few characters of the pickle itself -- the first few characters are the protocol version.  `2` starts like this: `\x80\x02`, while `3` starts like this: `\x80\x03`, etc.